# How to build Tesseract 4.0.0 version for iOS?

Tags: ios, cmake, tesseract

After installing Tesseract through CocoaPods:

```
pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
```

The function `[G8Tesseract version]` returns version number 3.03, but I expected to get version 4.0.

I assume the latest version 4.0 with LSTM can be built using `cmake`, but I do not know how to do it.

I ask those who know to help me build Tesseract 4.0 for iOS from the source code from an open repository: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract

Comment: What is unclear in [wiki page](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#macos)? It is directly referenced from the project's README.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do not understand how the commands specified in the wiki will help me in creating the framework. I tried them before asking a question.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/chaoskyme/Tesseract-OCR-iOS

Tesseract OCR iOS is a Framework for iOS7+, compiled also for armv7s and arm64. Update tesseract version to 4.00.00alpha.

^_^

Comment: Hi, how do I go about installing this particular version of Tesseract-OCR-iOS? Thanks!